# How do I fix DRASTIC performance difference in Civ 6 Singleplayer vs Multiplayer

Tags: games, steam, performance, amd-graphics, amd-ryzen

I get INSANELY different performance in civ 6 between multiplayer and single player, which doesn't make any sense to me. I can max things out in single player and have a buttery smooth experience, but even the minimum settings in multiplayer are unplayable. I honestly have no idea how to approach this because I've never had a problem like this before. Any and all help would be appreciated!

Video showing this "phenomena": https://youtu.be/VgamZaa9i8E

General system info:

```
    System:
    
      Host: GamingPC Kernel: 5.4.0-40-generic x86\_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc 
    
      v: 9.3.0 Desktop: Gnome 3.36.3 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
    
    Machine:
    
      Type: Desktop Mobo: ASUSTeK model: ROG STRIX B450-F GAMING v: Rev 1.xx 
    
      serial: <superuser/root required> UEFI: American Megatrends v: 2605 
    
      date: 08/06/2019 
    
    CPU:
    
      Topology: 6-Core model: AMD Ryzen 5 2600X bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Zen+ 
    
      rev: 2 L2 cache: 3072 KiB 
    
      flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4\_1 sse4\_2 sse4a ssse3 svm 
    
      bogomips: 86235 
    
      Speed: 1888 MHz min/max: 2200/3600 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1887 2: 1980 
    
      3: 1891 4: 2194 5: 1935 6: 1887 7: 1929 8: 2194 9: 2020 10: 2133 11: 2046 
    
      12: 2142 
    
    Graphics:
    
      Device-1: AMD Navi 10 \[Radeon RX 5600 OEM/5600 XT / 5700/5700 XT\] 
    
      vendor: XFX Pine driver: amdgpu v: kernel bus ID: 0a:00.0 
    
      Display: x11 server: [X.Org](https://X.Org) 1.20.8 driver: amdgpu 
    
      resolution: 1920x1080\~144Hz 
    
      OpenGL: renderer: AMD Radeon RX 5600 XT (NAVI10 DRM 3.35.0 
    
      5.4.0-40-generic LLVM 10.0.0) 
    
      v: 4.6 Mesa 20.0.8 direct render: Yes 
    
    Audio:
    
      Device-1: AMD Navi 10 HDMI Audio driver: snd\_hda\_intel v: kernel 
    
      bus ID: 0a:00.1 
    
      Device-2: AMD Family 17h HD Audio vendor: ASUSTeK driver: snd\_hda\_intel 
    
      v: kernel bus ID: 0c:00.3 
    
      Device-3: Logitech HD Pro Webcam C920 type: USB 
    
      driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo bus ID: 1-6:4 
    
      Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-40-generic 
    
    Network:
    
      Device-1: Intel I211 Gigabit Network vendor: ASUSTeK driver: igb 
    
      v: 5.6.0-k port: e000 bus ID: 03:00.0 
    
    Drives:
    
      Local Storage: total: 1.82 TiB used: 74.67 GiB (4.0%) 
    
      ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Samsung model: SSD 860 EVO 500GB size: 465.76 GiB 
    
      ID-2: /dev/sdb vendor: Western Digital model: WD10EZEX-08WN4A0 
    
      size: 931.51 GiB temp: 29 C 
    
      ID-3: /dev/sdc vendor: Crucial model: CT500MX500SSD1 size: 465.76 GiB 
    
      temp: 33 C 
    
    RAID:
    
      Message: No RAID data was found. 
    
    Partition:
    
      ID-1: / size: 456.96 GiB used: 15.95 GiB (3.5%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2 
    
    Info:
    
      Processes: 371 Uptime: 18m Memory: 15.62 GiB used: 3.57 GiB (22.9%) 
    
      Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 9.3.0 Shell: bash v: 5.0.17 
    
      inxi: 3.0.38
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not an answer to OPs question but might help others: had the exact same problem today, 250 FPS in single player, 10 in multiplayer. This was using the windows version of Civ VI on linux (i.e. "force use of a specific steam play compatibility tool"). Not on ubuntu though but on manjaro. In my case, the solution is to force *using proton 6* (6.3-8). proton versions 7, 8 or experimental all had the bad multiplayer performance, 6 works like a charm. It does require disabling the launcher:

```
eval $( echo "%command%" | sed "s/2KLauncher\/LauncherPatcher.exe'.*/Base\/Binaries\/Win64Steam\/CivilizationVI'/" )
```

in the launch options.